# JS Error: Cannot read property 'length'

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I want to get a random number from an array but I am getting the error: Cannot read property 'length'.

```
  //Attack arr
  var attackID = [0,1];

  //Start game
  function start(){
    console.log("Your new username is "+localuser.username+"!");
    var r_atk = Math.round(Math.random()*(attackID.length-1));

    if(attacks[r_atk] == 0){
      punch(enemy.name);
    }
    else if(attacks[r_atk] == 1){
      kick(enemy.name);
    }
  }
```

*To look at the full code click [Here](http://torin.eschweb.com/Random-Stuff/console-battles.html) and press ctrl + u*

Comment: the prompt to declare the username is not firing

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `start` function before defining the `attackID` array. Just move the `attackID` declaration inside `start()` since you aren't using it anywhere else anyway.

```
function start(){
  var attackID = [0,1];
  console.log("Your new username is "+localuser.username+"!");
  var r_atk = Math.round(Math.random()*(attackID.length-1));
  // ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be inside the function. It just needs to be above where `start` is run.

Comment: It doesn't have to, but it's the best place to put it, since it's referenced only inside the function body and nowhere else in the code.

Comment: Agreed. But it's something that should definitely be noted since it changes the scope of `attackID` in his code, which may end up being used elsewhere in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Revised**

The game's code actually contains two errors. The second error is not immediately apparent because it is obscured by the first error message. The issue is that **attacks** is neither a variable nor a property since it is never declared nor defined in the code so a ReferenceError will appear after you resolve the first error.

The first error message, visible in Google Chrome Developer Tools, states:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The console indicates that the problematic code is:

`var r_atk = Math.round(Math.random()*(attackID.length-1));`

Yet, the line of code itself is syntactically correct and **attackID** precedes the function declaration with a one-liner that declares and defines the variable.  You might think the solution is to catch the TypeError.  I tried that [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMeMNp?editors=1111) to no avail. The real issue concerns a concept called *[hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)* in which JavaScript variables and function declarations are moved to the top of the "...nearest surrounding scope" (see [here](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/)).  When **attackID** gets hoisted, it will evaluate as undefined. So, when start() executes, it hopelessly attempts to access a **length** property of an undefined variable, the end result yielding a TypeError.

A pragmatic solution involves deleting the line that specifically invokes start().  Since the function declaration of start() is at the end of the script you may convert it into an *immediately-invoked function expression* ([IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)).  To create an IFFE, put parentheses around the function declaration of start() and follow with another pair, enabling the function to automatically execute as well as avoid hoisting problems.  Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

> Function expressions in JavaScript are not hoisted, unlike function
>   declarations. You can't use function expressions before you define
>   them ...

Now, if you run the code, the TypeError associated with **attackID.length** vanishes since the array will be set before start() executes.

If you run the following code, you'll note the absence of the TypeError with respect to **attackID.length** which allows the ReferenceError message associated with **attacks** to appear.

```js
//Give user warning
console.warn("WARNING! This game is not close to being done yet\n\n\n\n");

function user(uname, HP, mana) {
  this.username = uname;
  this.HP = HP;
  this.mana = mana;
}

function enemy(ename, HP, mana) {
  this.name = ename;
  this.HP = HP;
  this.mana = mana;
}

var dmg = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 20, 30];
var enemy_dmg = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 20, 30];

//Create user
var localuser = new user(null, 100, 100);
var enemy = new enemy("enemy1", 100, 100);

//Set user name
var newName = prompt("What do you want your username to be?");
localuser.username = newName;

//Attacks
function punch(target) { // atk 0
  if (target == localuser.username) {
    var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (dmg.length - 1));
    localuser.HP -= dmg[r];
    console.log(enemy.name + " punched you! Your HP is now " + localuser.HP + "!");
  } else if (target == enemy.name) {
    var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (dmg.length - 1));
    enemy.HP -= dmg[r];
    console.log("You punched " + target + "! His HP is now " + enemy.HP + "!");
  } else {
    console.warn("Make sure you put quotes around the enemy's name.");
  }
}

function kick(target) { // atk 1
  if (target == localuser.username) {
    var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (dmg.length - 1));
    localuser.HP -= dmg[r];
    console.log(enemy.name + " kicked you! Your HP is now " + localuser.HP + "!");
  } else if (target == enemy.name) {
    var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (dmg.length - 1));
    enemy.HP -= dmg[r];
    console.log("You punched " + target + "! His HP is now " + enemy.HP + "!");
  } else {
    console.warn("Make sure you put quotes around the enemy's name.");
  }
}

//Attack arr
let attackID = [0, 1];

//Start game
(function start() {
  console.log("Your new username is " + localuser.username + "!");
    var r_atk = Math.round(Math.random() * (attackID.length - 1));
    if (attacks[r_atk] == 0) {
      punch(enemy.name);
    } else if (attacks[r_atk] == 1) {
      kick(enemy.name);
    }
})();
```

Related articles:

[David Walsh Blog](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yvJGeJKijAoJ:https://davidwalsh.name/fix-javascript-errors%20&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

[Understanding Undefined and Preventing Referenceerrors](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/)

[Older article on JS Best Practices](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/24-javascript-best-practices-for-beginners--net-5399)

Answer (score 0):

It is happening for you calling `start()` where `start()` accessing `attackID` before declaring it. You should `attackID` variable before using `start()` function. Or use inside function scope.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you call the function `start()` at line 38, but you only declare and assign the `attackID` array at line 74.

You must assign `attackID` inside the `start()` function, or you could declare and assign all your variables on the beginning of your file. Assigning all variables that will be reused, on top of your code, is a good code standard.

Comment: I think you mean assign, as opposed to declared. Declaring without assigning will still throw the error

Comment: Yes, exactly! Assing is the word...! You must declare it and assign the value for it.

Comment: I'd be a good idea to edit your original answer to reflect that. Otherwise, people might downvote.